# Thermodynamic adiabatic process, question regarding mathematical operations

Tags: thermodynamics, mathematics, calculus, adiabatic

I have a question regarding mathematical operations often seen in physics books:

In an adiabatic process the heat is 0, so by the first law of thermodynamics we have that $E = W$, and an infinitesimal change in energy equals an infinitesimal change in work (why?) so we have $dE = dW \rightarrow f/2NkdT = P dV = Nk\frac{T}{V}dV \rightarrow f/2\frac{dT}{T} = \frac{dV}{V}$ (where $f, N, k$ are constants).

**Now, the following step is what I dont understand:**
We integrate both sides with LHS from $T_i$ to $T_f$ and with RHS from $V_i$ to $V_f$:

$f/2\int_{T_i}^{T_f}\frac{dT}{T}$ = $\int_{V_i}^{V_f}\frac{dV}{V}$.

How can we integrate both sides with respect to different variables and know that they are equal? What is the mathematical justification behind this? I hope my question is not too diffuse.

Answer (score 1):

Since your question asks for mathematical justification I will answer purely mathematically, without digressing towards exact and inexact differentials or the physics behind your equations.

Your first question is basically the fact that if for two functions $f$ and $g$ it holds that $f(x)=g(x)$, $^\forall\!x\in\mathrm{dom}(f)\cap\mathrm{dom}(g)$, then $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}f(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}g(x)$, which you can re-express as  $\mathrm{d}f = \mathrm{d}g$.

Your second question is, similarly, the fact that if you have $$\alpha \frac{\mathrm{d}f}{f}=\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{g},$$ you can do an intermediate change of variables $f\to x$ and $g\to x$ to write
$$\alpha \frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\ \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{g(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}x}\ \mathrm{d}x$$
and integrate both sides over $X\subseteq \mathrm{dom}(f)\cap\mathrm{dom}(g)$ to get
$$\alpha \int_X\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{\mathrm{d}x}\ \mathrm{d}x = \int_X \frac{1}{g(x)}\frac{\mathrm{d}g}{\mathrm{d}x}\ \mathrm{d}x.$$
But this is the same as
$$\alpha \int_{f(X)}\frac{\mathrm{d}f}{f} = \int_{g(X)} \frac{\mathrm{d}g}{g}.$$

This can be further formalised (although it is an overkill at this stage) to avoid the intermediate use of $x\in X$, within differential geometry by using the pullback of a differential form.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the answer

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking you are right, there is no much meaning in integrating the different sides of an equation over different independent variables. But in the particular case that you have described, the situation this is not he case. The thing is that $T$ and $V$ are not independent variables. There is a relation between them (namely $TV^{\gamma-1}$, where $1-\gamma=2/f$ in your notation. Of course you do not know it at this stage of the calculation, but you know it is there and needs to be found).
Hence you may imagine there is a parameter, say a "reaction coordinate" $t$ that tells you how far you are into the process. Then both $T=T(t)$ and $V=V(t)$. Then you equation is in fact $$\frac{f}{2} \frac{1}{T}\frac{\partial T(t)}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{V}\frac{\partial V(t)}{\partial t} $$ now you just need to integrate both sides with respect to $t$: $$\frac{f}{2} \int_{t_i}^{t_f} \frac{1}{T}\frac{\partial T(t)}{\partial t} dt= \int_{t_i}^{t_f}\frac{1}{V}\frac{\partial V(t)}{\partial t} dt$$
which you can finally render as:

$$\frac{f}{2} \int_{T(t_i)}^{T(t_f)} \frac{1}{T}dT= \int_{V(t_i)}^{V(t_f)}\frac{1}{V}dV$$

As to your first "why?", the change in internal energy $E$ is equal to the work done $W$ ("change in work") by the definition of an adiabatic process.

Comment: thank you for the good answer.

Answer (score -2):

Before answering, some mistakes and some doubts about your question:

- mistake: first law of thermodynamics says that $dE = \delta W$, evaluating variation of internal energy as the work done on the system; it's not expressed in terms of absolute values of energy or work (what would be the absolute value of work?)
- doubt: what is $f$?

Answer to your question, since the integrands $\frac{dT}{T}$, $\frac{dV}{V}$ are not exact differentials, you need to explicitly define the integration path.

Assuming we're dealing with an adiabatic reversible process, these two conditions identify an isentropic transformation $dS = 0$ and thus the the integration path where you need to perform the integral. For a ideal gas, $dS = 0$ leads to transformations governed by $P V^{\gamma} = \text{const}$, or $T V^{\gamma -1} = \text{const}$.

Comment: $\frac{dT}{T}=d\text{ln}T$

Comment: + C(other variables)

Comment: Since when are dT and dV not exact differentials? They're state functions of the other state variables, aren't they?

Comment: + C(other variables). So that you need to know the transformation to properly define a consistent set of limits of integration. You can't put an arbitrary pair of $T$s and an arbitrary pair of $V$s